# Linux / OpenWRT - run bash script with console / stdout output

Tags: linux, boot, bash, shell, openwrt

I have a [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/) System for which I've wrote a small interactive shell script which displays a menu and based on the input, displays appropriate info to stdout.

For example:

```
== Please Select Option ==
[1] Display IP address
[2] Display VPN Status
[3] Display something else

Please enter your choice?
```

When I run the script manually (`menu.sh`) then it seems to work fine.
However, I need to find a way for the script to launch automatically when the OS is booted. So instead of seeing a shell propmpt, the user will see the output of the script, in this case, the menu system.

How do I go it?

Answer (score 2):

OpenWRT uses the Busybox `ash` as its shell, which seems to run the commands in `/etc/profile` on login.

If you want the script to run automatically when anyone logs in (which is probably only going to be `root` if this is a router), I think adding this to the bottom of your `/etc/profile` will work:

```
/full/path/of/menu.sh
```

and if you don't want the menu dropping to the shell when its completed, you need some additional logic to support that.

Comment: Perfect! Never occured to me to try the `/etc/profile`
Works perfect!
Thank you very much!